# Characteristic Equation Intgeration PDE

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I've got this PDE:

$$2u^3u_x+ u_y= x,\\ u(x,0) =\sqrt x$$

I've gotten the first steps out the way but I have the problem of the differential integration:

$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial \tau } = 2u^3 \\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial \tau } = 1\\ \frac{\partial u}{\partial \tau } = x$$

Now it's obvious how we solve the second $y = \tau + c_1$ and then the conditions to get $y = \tau$

But the problem arises from using charisteric method on (1) + (3) and trying to somehow fit those together.

If someone could help it would be really appreciated thank you

Comment: Maybe differentiate (3) wrt $\tau$ and then substitute (1) to obtain $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \tau^2}=2u^3$. Solve this ODE for $u$, then change $\tau\to y$ and use $u(x,0)=\sqrt{x}$ for the integration constant. I don't know if this is the best way, since wolfram gives a very complicated solution: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=u%27%27%28t%29+%3D+2u%28t%29%5E3

Comment: It might help to notice that since $u''=2u^3$, you get $((u')^2)' = (u^4)'$ so $(u')^2 = u^4 + c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$2u^3u_x+ u_y= x,\\ u(x,0) =\sqrt x \quad\text{supposing}\quad x\geq 0$$

You wrote :
$$\begin{cases}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \tau } = 2u^3 \\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial \tau } = 1\\ \frac{\partial u}{\partial \tau } = x
\end{cases}\quad\text{or equivalently to the Charpit-Lagrange form :}\quad \frac{dx}{2u^3}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{du}{x}=d\tau$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{2u^3}=\frac{du}{x}$ :
$$u^4-x^2=c_1$$
Before looking for a second characteristic equation one observe that the specified condition $u(x,0)=\sqrt{x}$ is defined on a characteristic curve $u^4-x^2=c_1=0$ since $u^4=x^2$. It is wellknown that if the condition is specified and satisfied on a characteristic curve the solution is not unique : they are an infinity of solutions. Among them the particular solution :
$$\big(u(x,y)\big)^4=x^2\quad\implies\quad \boxed{u(x,y)=\sqrt{x}}$$
satisfies both the PDE and the condition. This is a trivial solution of the problem.

Fortunately in the wording of the problem it is not asked to find all the solutions. In fact this would be difficult because a second characteristic equation involves a special function (Elliptic integral of first kind). The final result would includes an arbitrary function, thus leading to an infinity many solutions which all satisfies the condition $u(x,0)=\sqrt{x}$.